# Is "_NOUN_ who each _VERB_" grammatically correct?

Tags: quantifiers, who-whom

I just came across the following sentence;

> A company with 1,000 employees ***who each send*** eight e-mail messages per workday would produce two million messages per year.

where ***who each send*** sounds incorrect. ["who each send"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22who%20each%20send%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1h4rZvL3iAhWpShUIHXi5CngQ_AUIEigA&biw=1535&bih=794) (used in Google-Books)

After I tried to [compare ***"who each send"***, and ***"who all send"***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who%20each%20send%2Cwho%20all%20send&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20all%20send%3B%2Cc0) on Google-Ngrams, no ngram was found for the first one. So, is it grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is actually correct.

Another alternative to write the sentence would be:

> A company with 1,000 employees **who send** eight e-mail messages per workday **each**, would produce two million messages per year.

This reduces the confusion, as **each** and **send** are no longer together. **All** does not match the purpose, because **each** employee sends 8 email messages per day, not **all** of them only 8 messages.

Comment: I'd agree that 'all' is a bad alternative ^^, and that your modified-version of the sentence is better. However, I don't think the original sentence is grammatically sound. Is there a better alternative to 'each' while keeping the word other the same?

Comment: You can use "everybody", but it is definitely worse and ungrammatical. The original sentence is quite sound grammatically, even if it looks a bit strange.

Comment: 'everybody' would not even be an alternative to 'each' in that sentence. How about using 'each of who sends' instead of 'who each sends'?

Comment: I'm struggling to accept the first statement of your answer: "The sentence is actually correct.". ^^

Comment: Te sentence can work without using "each" at all. But in that case, it would be ambiguous, who sends emails? All of them only 8 messages, or each of them sends 8? The author decided to place "each" as a subject in the subordinate clause, in the first place (after "who"), before the verb ("sends").

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the original sentence. If you want to change it you could say *... employees, each of whoM sendS...* but it really has to be *whom* in this construction, not *who* as in your suggestion above, and you need the comma after *employees* and another one before *would*.